# Does using a crossbow with the Sharpshooter feat change its range in underwater combat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, ranged-attack, underwater

The ["Underwater Combat"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#UnderwaterCombat) section of the Combat chapter (PHB, p. 198) reads:

> A **ranged weapon attack** automatically misses a target beyond the weapon's normal range. Even against a target within normal range, the attack roll has disadvantage unless the weapon is a crossbow, a net, or a weapon that is thrown like a javelin (including a spear, trident, or dart).

The [Sharpshooter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/sharpshooter) feat (PHB, p. 170) reads:

> Attacking at long range doesn't impose disadvantage on your ranged weapon attack rolls.

With both of those in mind, would a PC with a Hand Crossbow and the Sharpshooter feat be able to shoot further than 30 feet underwater?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No: the maximum range is reduced.

The benefit is that the attack is not at disadvantage; you get that benefit from using a crossbow underwater.

This is one of those cases where the rules and verisimilitude tend to match up.  The sharpshooter feat can't remove disadvantage if the attack *automatically misses.*   There isn't even an attack roll to make if there's no chance to hit.
(If you take a page from PHB Chapter 7, the dice are only rolled when the outcome is in doubt).  What the Sharpshooter feat offers is a removal of disadvantage for long range when there is a chance, however large or small, to hit.

> A ranged weapon attack **automatically misses** a target beyond the
>   weapon’s normal range. Even against a target within normal range, the
>   attack roll has disadvantage unless the weapon is a crossbow, a net,
>   or a weapon that is thrown like a javelin (including a spear, trident,
>   or dart).  (Basic Rules, Ch 9; *Underwater Combat* ; bolded for emphasis)

From the Weapon Table:

> Crossbow, hand 75 gp 1d6 piercing 3 lb. Ammunition (range 30/120),
>   light, loading

Answer (score 3):

## Sharpshooter doesn't counter underwater combat rules.

As you said, Sharpshooter remove the disadvantage if you attack within your weapon's long range. However, the underwater combat rules state that :

> A ranged weapon attack **automatically misses** a target beyond the weapon's normal range.

It's not a disadvantage, the attack just miss. Sharpshooter doesn't interact with auto-miss. If you want a logical reason, imagine that the shot isn't more difficult to aim but the density of the water slowing down the ammunition remove any possibility of damage beyond a certain range.

As a note, if your weapon wasn't one of the specified type, you would also have disadvantage in the normal range since Sharpshooter only remove disadvantage caused by attacking with the weapon's long range.